# What does this mean Fin(A) = { X ⊆ A : X is finite }?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Im trying to solve the following question:     Let A be a countable set.  Prove that Fin(A) = { X ⊆ A : X is finite } is countable.
I'm not, however, sure what Fin(A) = { X ⊆ A : X is finite } means.
For example suppose A ={1,2}, does Fin(A) =  {1,2} or does Fin(A)  = {$nullset$, {1}, {2}, {1,2}} or does it equal something else altogether?
Am I supposed to show that there are countable subsets or countable total elements of all possible subsets ie union of all subsets ?

Does the following solution to the actual question make sense?  Let's consider sets of Fin(A) which have different cardinality; the smallest set has cardinality 1 and the largest will have cardinality n (which is countable).
Then for each cardinality size there will be at most countable number of elements since we  can for example differentiate sets by their smallest element (and if same then we proceed to next smallest element etc), then the total amount of such sets is a countable union of countable sets hence countable?

Comment: Fin(A) is the collection of finite subsets of A; if A is finite, Fin(A) is the power set of A

Comment: Thank you J.W. Tanner!

Comment: It looks like your struggling with definitions; consider the following: if $A = \{1,2\}$, then $X = \{1\}$ satisfies $X \subseteq A$, and $X$ is also finite. Therefore, it is an element of Fin$(A)$.

Comment: so if A = {1,2,3} then Fin(A) has 8 elements correct? ie {{1},{2},{3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2.3}, {1,2,3}, null set} correct?

Comment: that is correct; if $A$ has $n$ elements, then Fin($A$) has $2^n$

Comment: Im assuming that that is the if A is finite.  If A is infinite countable then Fin(A) will have fewer ements than $2^n$ elements

Comment: if A is infinite, then I wouldn't say A has *n* elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is saying that the collection of all finite subsets of A is countable.

To prove that note that $Fin(A)\subset \cup_n A^n$ so it’s a countable union of countable sets, hence countable. (I am hand waving a little bit, you can check it using some rigorous arguments).

For example, you can fix an indexing of $A$ By $\mathbb N$  and then map each subset $\{a_{i_1},...,a_{i_n}\}$ of cardinality $n$ to $(a_{i_1},...,a_{i_n})$ where $i_j$’S are in increasing order.

Comment: You mean countable union of finite sets?

Comment: I have edited there.